# Count duplicates in rows per column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a very long table like below:

```
    A    B    C    D    .......
0   au   br   gt   uy
1   cd   gq   gt   uy
2   fg   br   gt   ml
3   kl   br   gt   wx
```

..............

I would like to count and to print duplicates per column like:

```
A   0    
B   2     
C   3     
D   1
```

I have only found to count duplicates for one column:

```
df.duplicated(['B']).sum()
```

Do I have to write all columns (about 30) or is it possible to use something from pandas? I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
df.duplicated(df.loc[:,:]).sum()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtract length of DataFrame with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df = len(df) - df.nunique()
print (df)
A    0
B    2
C    3
D    1
dtype: int64
```

Or use[`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for get boolean mask for each column separately and `sum` for count of `True` values:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated()).sum()
print (df)
A    0
B    2
C    3
D    1
dtype: int64
```